# How to use Numpy vectorize to calculate columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a pd Dataframe and would like to calculate one column based on two others from the same dataframe. I would like to use Numpy vectorisation for this as the dataset is large.
Here is the dataframe:

```
Input Dataframe
   A    B
0  567  345
1  123  456
2  568  354

Output Dataframe
   A    B    C
0  567  345  567.345
1  123  456  123.456
2  568  354  568.354
```

where column C is a concatenation between A and B with dot between both values.
I am using apply():

```
df['C'] = df.apply(lambda row: str(row['A']) + '.' + str(row['B']), axis=1)
```

instead to iterate over rows/index etc. but still it is slow.
I know that I could do:

```
df['C'] = df['A'].values + df['B'].values
```

which is extremely faster, but this will not give me the desired result, and on the same time:

```
df['C'] = str(df['A'].values) + '.' + str(df['B'].values)
```

will give me something completely different.
The example is just for presentation purposes (the values of A and B could be of any type). The question is more general.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't need `numpy` here.

Answer (score 0):

A list comprehension should be faster then apply or such use case:

```
df['C'] = [f"{a}.{b}" for a,b in zip(df['A'],df['B'])]
```

---

Outputs

```
    A    B        C
0  567  345  567.345
1  123  456  123.456
2  568  354  568.354
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply - very useful. Indeed list comprehension is faster than apply(), but still no Numpy here. I tested it with 5 million rows, but if they are much more, or the calculation is more complex?

Comment: The problem is with string value where even vectorized operations take a hit . You can convert using astype and use str accessors which are though vectorized for a pandas series are still slower than a vanilla python loop. Loops aren't always blanket bad :) also np.vectorize isn't actually vectorized. You can look it up for more info

Answer (score 0):

To convert numbers to strings you can use the method `astype()`:

```
df['A'].astype('str') + '.' + df['B'].astype('str')
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mykola, here astype is a Nympy method - right? I am wondering than why astype() is slower than list comprehension mentioned in the other comment bellow?

Comment: `astype()` is a `pandas` method.